# Problem how to declare an array of composite type with Julia

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

I would like to declare a table with "indexes" type

```
tuple PM
{
npm
nvm
}

indexes=PM[]
push!(indexes,PM(1,"s"))
push!(indexes,PM(2,"s"))
push!(indexes,PM(1,"m"))
push!(indexes,PM(2,"m"))


int countPVX[indexes]
```

Comment: what problems have you faced with your approach?

Comment: @Rym, currently it is not clear what exactly you are asking. Could you please provide a minimal example of actual Julia code showing what you want, and what doesn't work or what error messages you are getting? Ideally in a form others can copy and paste into their REPL.

Comment: xref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/delaration-of-an-array-with-indexed-type/20399/2

Comment: While it is not a well worded question, it really is quite obvious what they probably want. I hope the downvoters cut some slack. I can attest to Julia being confusing the first time around to use...

Comment: @CharlieCrown I don't up- or downvote to be nice or mean. It is not a good question, it shows nearly zero effort on the part of the person who posted it (neither in phrasing the question, nor in even learning the most basic syntax), and it is not useful for others. It has also been cross-posted to at least two other fora, with no explanation or follow-up. My down-vote remains until the poster shows some good-faith effort to follow up or improve the question.

Comment: @CharlieCrown It still is honestly not clear to me whether you have guessed right. I mean, except for defining `PM` correctly, the `indexes` part already worked. But then they mention "table" and "indexes type"? And the last line doesn't even make sense if you think in C terms, does it?

Answer (score 4):

I am not exactly sure of what you are after, but you could make a list

### Edit:

as recommended by SalchiPapa, and also as in the original post... indexes = PM[]

```
struct PM
    npm
    nvm
end

indexes = PM[]
push!(indexes,PM(1,"s"))
push!(indexes,PM(2,"s"))
push!(indexes,PM(1,"m"))
push!(indexes,PM(2,"m"))

println(indexes)
```

The output is a list of these structs

```
Any[PM(1, "s"), PM(2, "s"), PM(1, "m"), PM(2, "m")]
```

Note, if you know what types `npm` and `nvm` are, I recommend stating them, i.e., `npm` looks like it is always an `integer`, and `nvm` looks like it is always a `String`

```
struct PM
    npm::Int64
    nvm::String
end
```

you can access these elements simple as, for example:

```
indexes[2].npm
```

which in this case outputs `2` and `indexes[2].nvm` would output `s`.

Comment: You can also declare `indexes` as: `indexes = PM[]`

Comment: Good to know... I have only been doing Julia for a couple of weeks myself

Comment: Despite what I wrote above, this _is_ a decent interpretation given the limited information. But using `indexes = PM[]`, as SalchiPapa suggested, would be a huge improvement indeed.

Comment: The more I look at it, it looks like it is supposed to be an array of [arrays of composite types]. My answer is a solution to the title of the problem...

Comment: You could also type the array literal as is: `[PM(1, "s"), PM(2, "s"), PM(1, "m"), PM(2, "m")]` in one go, instead of pushing the elements. This will infer the type of the array to be `Vector{PM}`, instead of `Vector{Any}`.